# Security+ issue, Android 12 or 13 won't install the apk Ithat I created

Tags: android, security, apk

Android wont install apk due to security reasons, i think it has been patched and now im stuck and cant proceed learning.

I tried to install it and received the above attached pop-up, I don't if I should revert to android 10 or 11, if there is another way I will the help.

[image]

Comment: Tap "Install anyway".